# How to build a complex layer-list layout for Splash Screen

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm actually building an app in which I have to put a Splash Screen. I saw that the best way to make one is by making a `layer-list` drawable (https://plus.google.com/+AndroidDevelopers/posts/Z1Wwainpjhd).

My problem is how can I make the layout I want by using a `layer_list` drawable, How can I **locate/position elements** with size, margins, gravity etc?

I would like to build this structure of layout:

[image: Splash Screen Layout]

Thank you for help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While you can't exactly locate or manipulate view elements in a layer list, you *can* add multiple items to it and anchor them on the drawable as shown in your image.

I don't have access to my computer right now but I imagine it would look something like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:drawable="@color/gray"/>

    <item>
        <bitmap
            android:gravity="left|start"
            android:src="@drawable/logo1"/>
    </item>
    <item>
        <bitmap
            android:gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/logo2"/>
    </item>
    <item>
        <bitmap
            android:gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/text1"/>
    </item>
    <item>
        <bitmap
            android:gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/text2"/>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

If something like this doesn't work, then what you could do is create an image containing everything you want to display for your splash screen (the two logos and text), and just display that one drawable as your splash screen.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:drawable="@color/gray"/>

    <item>
        <bitmap
            android:gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/imageWithEverythingInIt"/>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

Comment: how to make sure that the bitmap covers the screen end to end?

Comment: @prateek31 use android:gravity="fill"